# Who is credited for this theorem on bounding boxes for an ellipse?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

Not long ago I found an animated gif on the web that showed a carpenter's square placed on an ellipse such that both arm's of the square remained in contact with the ellipse at all times. The gif traced out the loci formed by the intersection of the square's arms, and that was a circle! Now, I thought, how cool is that? So I took the challenge and proved this result analytically.

I worded the theorem as follows:

> The loci of the vertices of all rectangular bounding boxes of an
>   ellipse with semi major and semi minor axes $a$ and $b$ respectively
>   form an ellipse centered circle of radius $c=\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$,
>   independent of the angle between the ellipse axes and bounding box
>   edges.

(I tried to upload an image, but SE wouldn't let me!)

I have two (related) questions about this 'theorem':

1. What's this theorem called?
2. Who is credited for 'discovering' it?

Comment: To whomever it was that left the comment calling this circle a *Director Circle*, I thank you. Why did you delete your comment!

Comment: I was googling for the one who found this property for a fuller reply, so temporarily deleted it, but never could find his name..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result is perhaps called the *Director Circle*. Is it like this? A special case shown..

[Director Circle Ellipse](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-director-circle-of-curve-x-2-3+y-2-3-a-2-3)

Comment: Yes, that's it. Thanks. Do you have any idea who is credited for it?

Comment: @OneMug I suspect it is in Apollonius of Perga's Conics, but I'd have to look through it to find a proposition number.

Comment: @MichaelBiro - After some Googling, I think you're correct. If it's a quick search for you, I would like to know, but the proposition number is for my own curiosity/completeness, and a lot more detail than expected! Don't spend a lot of time tracking it down. Thanks for the info.